# Accessing MySQL through Javascript via PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

When any user logs in, I just want to send 2 parameters to PHP and then want to update related DB table. Is it possible in javascript? If possible any sample code or links appreciated.

Comment: you are better off using PHP call itself to update Database entries than using JavaScript, Ajax is your friend if you really need to implement this in JS only.

Comment: @drachenstern: I assume you didn't read the question carefully, the OP wants to update two values, WHEN THE USER LOGS IN (let's take sign in count for example - just assuming - lets say the OP wants to update the sign_in count for the user). This can be easily achieved by adding an afterLogin() function in PHP which would update these values after every login - SEE MOM NO AJAX! :) And again, i think you didnt read my comment carefully either - I mentioned Ajax there - which is same as what Delan talked about.  The scenario might be different for sure..

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to request a PHP script using `XMLHttpRequest`, and include some database interaction with MySQL in the PHP script.

Comment: Thank for response @Delan Azabani, @drachenstern and every one. You are right @drachenstern. I am trying it from long back but the JS/AJAX are not getting connected to PHP. I need some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is the key you're looking for.

A javascript framework such [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) could help you a lot. There's several built in AJAX methods related in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/), specially [this method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Answer (score 0):

It is really pretty simple using JQuery, as pedrorezende said. The easiest way would be something like

```
$.post('sample/path?var1=value&var2=otherValue');
```

---

Edit: here is the full code, I believe this would accomplish what you want (untested):

```
<script type="tex/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#login_form").submit(function() {
     $.post("login_handler.php", $("#login_form").serialize());
  }
</script>
<body>
    <form id="login_form">
        <input type="text" name="username"></input>
        <input type="text" name="password"></input>
        <input type="submit" value="login">
    </form>
</body>
```

The first script will [load JQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery).

The second script [creates the handler](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) and [sends the form data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to an external PHP file.

Then in `login_handler.php` you would send your query to MySQL using the `$_POST` values.

Comment: Do I need to call this function using external interface if required like using callback?